# problem when processing selected list

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, list, custom-controller

[image]i'm confuse how to process my selected list,
here is my vfpage :

```
<apex:page controller="preProcessController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="PreProcessPayroll" title="Pre Process Payroll" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false" >

             <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Payroll Name" for="listPeriod"/>
                <apex:selectList id="listPeriod" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPeriod}" style="width:150px"> 
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Period}"/> 
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="listEmployee"/>
                </apex:selectList>   
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

            <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="All Employee" />
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="ProcessAll" value="{!ProcessAll}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="listEmployee" />
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

            <apex:panelGroup id="listEmployee">
                <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Employee" leftOptions="{!allEmployee}" 
                                       rightLabel="Selected Employee" rightOptions="{!selectedEmployee}" 
                                       rendered="{! !ProcessAll}" size="14" width="475px"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>              
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton id="RunPreProcess" value="Run Pre Process" action="{!RunPreprocess}"/>           
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

then here is my custom controller :

```
public with sharing class preProcessController{ 
     public SelectOption[] selectedEmployee {get; set;}
     public String selectedPeriod{get; set;}
     public String picklistVal;
     public boolean ProcessAll {get; set;}


//========== get picklist value for Period Code ==========      
public List<selectOption> getPeriod() {        
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); 
    options.add(new selectOption('', '- None -')); 
    for (PYSETPAYPERIOD__c perCode : [SELECT Id, Name, Process_Flag__c FROM PYSETPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Process_Flag__c < 4 OR Process_Flag__c = NULL ORDER BY Name]) {         
        options.add(new selectOption(perCode.id, perCode.Name));       
    } 
    return options;
}   

//get all employee record
 public LIST<SelectOption> getallEmployee(){      
    LIST<HREMPINFO__c> empMember = [SELECT Id, Name, Full_Name__r.Name FROM HREMPINFO__c WHERE Id IN 
                                    (SELECT Employee_No__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod)
                                    ORDER BY Name];        
    LIST<HREMPASSIGNMENT__c> empAssignment = [SELECT Position_Name__c, Position_Name__r.Name, Employee_No__c, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c
                                              WHERE Start_Date__c <=: System.today() AND (End_Date__c >=: System.today() OR End_Date__c =: Null)];

    LIST<SelectOption> empList = new LIST<SelectOption>();

    MAP<String, String> picklistVal  = new MAP<String, String>();

    for(HREMPINFO__c eM : empMember){
    for(HREMPASSIGNMENT__c eA : empAssignment){
        if(eA.Employee_No__c == eM.Id){
            if(!picklistVal.containskey(eA.Employee_No__c)){
                picklistVal.put(eA.Employee_No__c, eM.Full_Name__r.Name + ' - ' + eM.Name + ' - ' +eA.Position_Name__r.Name);
                empList.add(new SelectOption(eM.Id, picklistVal.get(eA.Employee_No__c)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return empList;
    }

    public void RunPreprocess(){
        if(selectedPeriod != NULL){
           //query into emp pay periode based on selected period on vf page
    PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c[] empPayPeriod = [SELECT Period__r.Element_Name__r.Budget_Item_Code__c, Employee_No__r.Company_Name__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Group__c, 
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Type__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Content_Value__c, Employee_No__r.Id, 
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.End_Date__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Display__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Order__c,
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.Is_Value__c, Period__r.Period__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Process_Sequence_ID__c, 
                                        Period__r.Element_Name__r.Start_Date__c, Assignment__r.Id FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod];
    PYSETPAYPERIOD__c setPayPeriod = [SELECT Name, Process_Flag__c FROM PYSETPAYPERIOD__c WHERE id =: selectedPeriod];

    //create array of PYEMPELEMENT
    PYEMPELEMENT__c[] empElement = new PYEMPELEMENT__c[]{};

    //create single record of PYEMPELEMENT
    PYEMPELEMENT__c e = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();

    //create PYEMPELEMENT as much as employee element count    
    for(PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c pp : empPayPeriod) {
        e = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();
        e.Budget_Item_Code__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Budget_Item_Code__c;
        e.Company_Name__c = pp.Employee_No__r.Company_Name__r.Id;
        e.Element_Group__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Group__c;
        e.Element_Name__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Id;
        e.Employee_No__c = pp.Employee_No__r.Id;
        e.Period__c = pp.Period__r.Period__r.Id;
        e.Process_Flag__c = 2;
        e.Assignment__c = pp.Assignment__r.Id;

            empElement.add(e);


    }
            insert empElement;


        }       

   }
}
```

Comment: What specifically is your question.

Comment: when i choose an option from my vf page, it cant process method in my custom controller (in this case public void RunPreProcess button)
here my snapshot : http://prntscr.com/cme6om
what i want to achieve is, when the button clicked, it would insert a new record based on my RunPreProcess method

Comment: Sorry. Don't do links here. Update your question with more details as well as any images to support it.

Comment: ok then, i already edit my question @Eric

Answer (score 1):

```
 public PageReference selectedPeriod() {
     return null;
 }
```

Reading through your code, I really don't understand what is this method doing here. Please remove this piece of code. As you are having two selectedPeriod, one is a String and the other is a method, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir, i'm really appreciate it! but it still not work @Lance Shi i think my problem is : when i get the selected option in my list. Because i already try in my debug tes, which is i'm directly choose the period Id, it work! But when i try with my selected period based on my choice, it doesnt work,
any idea sir?

Comment: @Vikolai Can you try add a System.debug(selectedPeriod); line before `if(selectedPeriod != null)` statement in your RunPreprocess() method? And let me know the result.

Comment: Hmmm it doesn't show anything sir @Lance Shi

Comment: @Vikolai Do you have any jQuery code in your page or is it everything?

Comment: Above is all my vf page, just that, nothing else hehe @Lance Shi

Comment: @Vikolai if you comment out all the code in RunPreprocess() method and put only System.debug('Hello'). Will you be able to get it in the debug log?

Comment: nothing happen sir @Lance Shi
it means i got problem with my button?

Comment: @Vikolai Yes. It means your button is not correctly linked with your controller's function. I am not sure why was that though. I can't reproduce that in my org

Comment: hmm, i'm trying to remove all my code, it still not work, my button still cant print out anythig, take a look , my controller : http://prntscr.com/cmf26n
and my vf : http://prntscr.com/cmf2pv. 
my result before click button : http://prntscr.com/cmf34x
after click button : http://prntscr.com/cmf3i7
@Lance Shi

Comment: @Vikolai I am getting 'Hello' in my debug log using the code you provided me. Except I have removed your custom component. So I am thinking, the issue can be in: 1 security, 2 your component. Anyway, it is not in the code you have provided

Comment: hmm, what is the meaning of security? can u explain it to me? @Lance Shi